# How do I lose fat? I tried cycling but it does not work

Tags: bicycling, bellyfat

I am doing cycling from last 6 months for loss of fat. I have a fat belly and my friends always makes joke on this. This is the reason I started cycling.

But I did not get any result

**Please give me some tips for fat loss.**

Comment: Do cardio before eating breakfast

Answer (score 2):

The belly is probably the most 'stubborn' of all the areas to lose fat from. Even after you have trimmed down all the other body parts and toned up, its still an uphill battle to get at least a little definition in the belly area.

The way fat burning works in your body is determined purely by genetics. Not by the exercise you are doing or how quickly or slowly you are doing it, but rather, your genetics, activity level (in general) and diet. As it relates to your cycling, that is a good start, but it may not be adequate enough for you. Especially if you just began, it will take a while before you start seeing any results, let alone in your belly area. I would advise you to mix it up a little. Mix some cardio, with some resistance training. Go for a jog, do some circuit training and adjust your diet for complex starches, lean protein, greens, water. Cut down everything else not in those categories (moderation is key).

[Here](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/cardio-fitness-challenges-4-fat-burning-workouts.html) are a few workouts that you can do to the tune of losing some weight and toning up the stubborn parts of your body.

Answer (score 1):

### Weight is lost primarily through diet, not by exercise.

Unfortunately, you don't say how much fat you have, how old you are, how fast or long you ride, but, the single thing we can say is that over a long enough time frame, if you eat at a calorie deficit you will lose weight, if you eat a calorie surplus you will gain weight.

[A 30 min ride at 13 miles/hour burns about 300 Calories](http://www.bicycling.com/training-nutrition/training-fitness/cycling-calories-burned-calculator) this is mot much more than a [600ml bottle of Coke which clocks in at 260 Calories](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/coca-cola-australia-coke-600ml-25076549).

Track your diet and weight daily, calculate you [Total Daily Energy Expenditure](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) and aim for not much more than a 100-200 Calorie deficit per day. If you are losing weight to slowly eat a little less, if you are losing more than about 1 kilogram/2 pounds per week, consider eating a little more to ensure you are eating enough.

There al pleanty of questions here on diet tracking and weight loss, so I'd suggest searching here if you have more questions.

Comment: "A 30 min ride at 13 miles/hour" not even close to the word "exercise."

Comment: @alex Well, unfortunately the OP gives no indication of how long or fast they are riding. If they were riding faster and longer, I doubt they'd be having trouble with pesky fat.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr hey i ride daily total 40 kms and i ride slowly not so fast..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase results is an increase volume and speed of your ride. You can ride at speed 30 km/h for two-three hours (2000-2500 kcal) couple times a week, and one hour (1000 kcal) 3-4 times a week. It will give you significant increase of calories burned at aerobic level fat burning exercise. 10000 kilo-calories burned per week will give you ability to loose 0.5-1 kg per month or more. 
You need road bike for it.